# Inbound/Outbound rules resetting automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I'm deploying a python flask app on elastic beanstalk. The configuration is as follows:

```
VPC ID: vpc-XXX
Associate Public IP Address: false
Instance subnets: subnet-X1
ELB subnets: subnet-X1
ELB visibility: internal
```

After deploying the app works for few minutes and then dies with the following error:

```
Instance ELB health state has been "OutOfService" for 10 minutes: Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively.
```

I have found out that the inbound and outbound rules being used by security group for elastic load balancer disappear/reset on their own. If I manually set these rules again, the app works for sometime and then fails again in the same manner as described above. Is there some other settings that I should look at?